# How to use an object in more than one form in Visual C#?

Tags: c#, forms, class, object

I'm new in c#. I have read some book about c# for beginners. Now i can code simple applications. I have 2 forms and 1 class in a project. I want to use a object from that class in 2 forms. I want first form to set a property of the object and secont to display this property. How can i do it. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the constructor of the second form to take the class instance as a parameter.

For example:

```
public partial class PopupForm : Form {
    public PopupForm(MyClass instance) {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Do things with instance
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i coldnt write code for constructor. Can you write code for me please?

Comment: @togrul94, what is the problem that you're having?  The general syntax for a constructor is `public ClassName(ParamClass var1, ParamClass2 var2){ ..code.. }`.  So in your example, it might be `public MyForm2(MyClass var1){ ..do something.. }`.